# Decrypt hashes or create new hashes only from the timestamp

Tags: hash, timestamp

I am working on a project and I know that the hash I have contains a time stamp and I want to recreate it with my current time stamp. I have already tried identify the hash but I had no success and the hash is unknown. The hash has a dot at the end and all others of its kind have one like that at the end. Since I think it contains important information I don't want to give it out publicly, the question now is, is it possible to regenerate a hash that contains a timestamp with a different timestamp?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample code and sample values? It's not quite clear what you are doing and what you are trying for.

Comment: Sorry I think there's still not quite enough context for us to understand what your code does and what you want to do.

Comment: I cant tell everything, sry, but they are tokens and they are expired and i cant get a new one also i know that the informations are the same in the tokens the only thing what is different is the timestamp in them, i dont know the algorythm or anything else about those. If anything thinks this is possible and how to do something like this, it would be great

Comment: If it is encrypted you should not be able to replace the contents. But if it's a decrypted JWT or something like that you can decode it (try here: https://jwt.io/), then create a new one. For any properly encrypted token, you should have to decrypt the token, change the values, then encrypt again. It should be impossible to update a value otherwise.

Comment: I deleted the codes, yea idk how to decrypt them.